# Iterate directory using for loop and use the files found as variable

Tags: python

How can I make the file found from the directory as `file1` and `file 2`?

In my directory

```
dir = f/myfiles
```

I have some files:

```
a_MUS.txt
b_KILL.txt
c_MUS.txt
d_KILL.txt
```

I need the files that have the word "KILL" in their name to be as `file1` and `file2`:

```
file1 = b_KILL.txt
file2 = d_KILL.txt
```

My code as for now:

```
for files in os.listdir(dir)

    if "KILL" in files:

    print(files)
```

Comment: appending to a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to get just the filenames with "KILL" in it, and then unpack the items from that list into `file1` and `file2`. This assumes you know for certain there will be 2 such files.

```py
KILL_files = [filename for filename in os.listdir(dir) if "KILL" in filename]
file1, file2 = KILL_files
```